# How do I use two Vertex Buffers?

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer

I have two buffers I created like this:

```
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint vbo[2];

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glGenBuffers(2, vbo);

    // 1
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle), triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // 2
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(rectangle), rectangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

The first one has to create a triangle and the second one a rectangle.
So I am calling `glDrawArrays()` in the rendering loop like this:

```
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 3);         // Triangle

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 4);         // Rectangle
```

So why doesn't this work?
(PS: I know GL_TRIANGLES is used nowdays, but for this project I have to use GL_POLYGON)

Answer (score 2):

I case of a VBO and vertex attribute pointers, it's not that important which VBO is bound but which VBO is attached to the attribute. The VBO-attribute binding is established with the `glVertexAttribPointer` call, which means that calling it a second time with the same attribute index will unbind the first one.

You either have to establish the binding before each draw call, like:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)0);
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 3);         // Triangle

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)0);
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 4);         // Rectangle
```

Or you could use two VAO, setup each on their own and switch VAO during rendering.

If your geometry is fixed and you always have to render these two geometries, I would think about combining the two geometries in one VBO and use the first parameter of the `glDrawArrays` command to draw the geometries. This should lead to better performance since you need less state changes. The code for this would be something like:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glGenBuffers(1, vbo);

// Allocate memory for both geometries
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle) + sizeof(rectangle), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//Copy geometries one after the other to the VBO
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(triangle), triangle);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle), sizeof(rectangle), rectangle);

//Attribute binding
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Rendering:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 3);         // Triangle
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 3, 4);         // Rectangle
```